# Is it possible to rewrite $X^* A X = B$ in ${\operatorname{vec}}(X)$, where $X \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$, $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is it possible to vectorize the quadratic $$X^* A X = B$$ in ${\operatorname{vec}}(X)$, where $X \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times m}$, $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, and $B \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times m}$?

Apologies if it is trivial. I just don't know how to proceed. Your help will be highly appreciated.

---

I thought of using [Kroncker Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products). But it can represent only one side of the quadratic equation, i.e., either $X^*$ or $X$.

---

Partial attempt:

${\operatorname{vec}} (X^* A X) = \left( I \otimes X^* A \right) {\operatorname{vec}} (X) = {\operatorname{vec}} (B)$, then how to pull out $X^*$ from the Kronecker product? I want to represent the quadratic form in only ${\operatorname{vec}} (X^*)$ and ${\operatorname{vec}} (X)$.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to frame this in terms of column-vectors is to use the columns of $X$.  That is, if $x_j$ is the $j$th column of $X$, then we can write
$$
X^*AX = \sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{k=1}^m x_j^*Ax_k
$$

Comment: Maybe it would help if you could say a bit more about what framing your quadratic interms of $\operatorname{vec}(X)$ is supposed to accomplish; I suspect that there is no useful way to do this.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, thank you for your reply and a suggestion. I need in terms of ${\operatorname{vec}}(X)$ and ${\operatorname{vec}}(X^*)$ because I am trying to work out on optimization problem that requires in vectorization form since my other constraints are in vectorized form. it seems that there is no useful way to do this

Answer (score -1):

See [Wikipedia Vectorization Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)).

Comment: Thank you. I have noticed that and also gave the same reference. But it pulls out only one side of the quadratic equation. So, sorry this doesn't help me.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, you should be able to use it multiple times, first to introduce vec(X) and then to introduce vec(X+).

Comment: ${\operatorname{vec}} (X^* A X) = \left( I \otimes X^* A \right) {\operatorname{vec}} (X) = {\operatorname{vec}} (B)$, then how to proceed?

Comment: (X+)*A=I*(X+)*A=(AT kr I) vec(X+) (if I didn't screw it up).  Sorry for the poor rendering, I'm in a hurry...

Comment: @learning I think that John's point is that we can write $\operatorname{vec}(X^*A) = (A^T \otimes I) \operatorname{vec}(X^*)$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Thanks.  But after some more thought, my answer really doesn't address the question...